# How to convert datetime.strptime() weird date format ( with the word "of" in it)?

Tags: python

Is it possible to convert string to datetime object, when I got this kind of date format:

```
9th of April 2015 03:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
t = '9th of April 2015 03:00'
prefix = t.split()[0][-2:]
datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%d{0} of %B %Y %H:%M'.format(prefix))

datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 3, 0)
```

**Updated:** However I believe @alecxe's answer is the best among for general use case.

Comment: @IrmantasŽelionis, my answer may suit your use case, but in general I do believe alexce's answer is the best among.

Answer (score 4):

You can also let [`dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) do the job:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> s = "9th of April 2015 03:00"
>>> parse(s)
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 3, 0)
```

Comment: definitely the best way of going about it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to specify a correct position and type for your datetime objects!

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('9th of April 2015 03:00','%dth of %B %Y %H:%M')
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 3, 0)
```

*Note* that as mentioned in comment you can't use of this recipe for other strings that contain other numbers of day like `1st` and `2nd`, so as a more general way as @alecxe mentioned you can use `dateutil.parser.parse`

Comment: This won't work for other ordinal numbers - `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd`, etc.

Comment: Yes, and i just attempt to answer to question based on the OP's request that wants a solution for `datetime.strptime`. any way i'll mentioned it.