# how to parse a string date to a proper date format?

Tags: python

I am using a python "datefinder" library to obtain a "datetime" object. However, i encountered some issues where i have a string: "the 6m day of June 2012" and the "datefinder" library could not generate the correct date of that string.

I have tried using

```
datefinder.find_dates(date)
Result: 2012-06-13 00:00:00
```

The above result certainly is wrong and i realized the culprit is the "6m" word.

How do i convert the string "the 6m day of June 2012" to a proper format like "6 June 2012"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert datetime.strptime() weird date format ( with the word "of" in it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522341/how-to-convert-datetime-strptime-weird-date-format-with-the-word-of-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, It gives the o/p you want :

```
import datetime

p = datetime.datetime.strptime('the 6m day of June 2012','the %dm day of %B %Y')
print(p)
```

O/p is like :

```
2012-06-06 00:00:00
```

If you want it in desired format `06 June 2012` you can use this :

```
print(p.strftime("%d %B %Y"))
```